# Markov processes in paper "Recent Contributions to The Mathematical Theory of Communication"

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, information-theory, markov-process

I was reading the well-known paper by Warren Weaver, "[Recent Contributions to
The Mathematical Theory of Communication](http://www.designingasociety.org/evergreen/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/weaver.pdf)", I stumpled upon the following sentence(p. 5)"

> A  system  which  produces  a  sequence  of  symbols
>   (which may, of course, be letters or musical notes, say,
>   rather than  words) according to  certain probabilities is
>   called  a
>   stochastic  process
>   ,  and  the  special  case  of  a
>   stochastic process **in which the probabilities depend on
>   the  previous  events**,  is  called  a
>   Markoff  process
>   or  a
>   Markoff chain.

I am aware that Markoff chains are indepdent on the previous states of the system, formally :

$Prob(X_{k} = j_{k} / X_{k-1} = j_{k-1} ... X_{0} = j_0) = Prob(X_{k} = j_{k} / X_{k-1} = j_{k-1}) ~(*)$

Where, obviously, the chain consists of a finite set of states $S$ and the transition probabilities from state i to j $P_{ij}$ are characterized by (*)

Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think so; I think there is some error in that sentence (it should be "do not depend" or similar).

Comment: That's what I'm wondering too, even in the book "The mathematical theory of communication" by Illinois featuring shannon's and weaver's papers, the sentence is the same... :/

Comment: It's a dubious description, indeed - even in that informal-descriptive context. A process on which "the probabilities depend on previous events" is no a "special case" but the most general case. A Markoff (or Markov) process is not that, but a special subset of those process. But your formula (which is a first-order Markov chain) does not imply independence "on the previous states of the system", quite on the contrary: the current state depends on the previous state - only that, given the immediately previous state, it does not depend on the more distant past.

Answer (score 1):

The author is trying to describe one of the distinctive qualities of Markov chains.

In many stochastic processes, the value of the next symbol is entirely independent of the previous one. If, for example, we have $x_n$ where $x_n \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ (eg outcomes when a die is thrown), then the value of $x_{n+1}$ is independent of $x_n$. In a Markov process, however, the possible values of $x_{n+1}$ do depend on the current value of $x_n$ and the probabilities will be different, too. So we could have a situation where $x_n=1$ can be followed only by $x_{n+1}=3$ (with probability 30%) or $x_{n+1}=6$ (with probability 70%) and $x_n=2$ can be followed by $x_{n+1}=2$ (with probability 50%) or $x_{n+1}=3$ (with probability 50%). Thus both the probabilities and the possible next events depend on the previous events.

Comment: So I guess the author's description is just poor.

Comment: To the extent that it has not helped you, yes, it is poor.